# R how can I get the same type of values in factor in data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

> a <-c("house","house","office","house","house","office","company","company")

i would like to return

house 4
office 2
company 2

and one more i want to return only if it has greater than 2 occurancy
like

house 4

so that only house would be returned

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

`data_count <- table(dataset_name_here)`

This will give you a list of the elements and their count.

Comment: do i have to download the package?

Comment: it says there's no function data_count

Comment: i changed my question simpler can you help me?

Comment: data count isn't a function, its the data frame that the data from the table function is going into, thus, `data_count <- table( a )` where a is your dataset

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to work with your example data, but assuming that you have that worked out similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(dates = c(9565,9567,9569,9571,9573,9577), 
                type = c("",NA,"office","condo","office","house"),
                sfd = c("A","B","A","A","B","B"))
```

which gives

```
> df
  dates   type sfd
1  9565          A
2  9567   <NA>   B
3  9569 office   A
4  9571  condo   A
5  9573 office   B
6  9577  house   B
```

then `count` on the building type or whichever column you wish. You can also count on multiple columns, order does not matter. N.B. `type` here is a column name, not a keyword parameter.

```
count(df, type)
count(df, type, sfd)
count(df, sfd, type)
```

for

```
    type    sfd     n
  (fctr) (fctr) (int)
1             A     1
2  condo      A     1
3  house      B     1
4 office      A     1
5 office      B     1
6     NA      B     1
```

**EDIT**: OK, you have now changed the question a lot by changing the data, the data type, etc. But, a solution to what you are now asking is given by

```
a <-data.frame(c("house","house","office","house","house","office","company","company"))
freqdf <- data.frame(table(a))
```

for

```
company   house  office 
      2       4       2
```

you then want to subset df to only those that exceed a value, so

```
freqdf[apply(freqdf, MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x>3)), ]
```

yielding

```
  a Freq
```

2 house    4

as only the second element, `house` has a value > 3.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want but can i ask u one more question?

Comment: I'm wondering there might be more variable than condo house office but i can't check the rest of them..

Comment: Error in count(df_active3$df_active3.CURRENT_USE, type = c("sfd", "house")) : 
  unused argument (type = c("sfd", "house"))

Comment: and its not the data frame its a factor and i want the value that how many times that condo has been appeared

Comment: I changed my question can you please answer that? I want that information sorry for bothering you